# Connect to local SQL Server(IP address) via browser PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

I'm developing an website in HTML,PHP,etc... on shared hosting.
I have a local machine that has SQL Server and SSMS 2014 with information that i need to get on that website.
On my shared host i have this php settings: 
[image]

Drivers of ODBC: [image]

I have already connected via ip address to db in other local machine but when i try connect on browser i get the same error over and over.

I tried with sqlsrv_connect: (im not showing the ip for security reasons)

```
$serverName = "127.0.0.1"; 
$uid = "admin";   
$pwd = "admin***";  
$databaseName = "mydb"; 

$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                            
                     "PWD"=>$pwd,                            
                     "Database"=>$databaseName); 

// Connect using SQL Server Authentication. 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);  

if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
  foreach( $errors as $error ) {
    echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
    echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
    echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
  }
}
$tsql = "SELECT mor1_emp,mor2_emp,mor3_emp FROM rh_company";  


sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

I tried with PDO odbc:

```
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=testdb;host={$db_host1}";
    $connection = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=mydb; Uid=admin;Pwd=admin***;");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
}
```

I tried with PDO mssql:

```
try {
  $hostname = "127.0.0.1";            //host
  $dbname = "mydb";            //db name
  $username = "admin";            // username like 'sa'
  $pw = "admin***";                // password for the user

  $dbh = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
   $stmt->execute();
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
     print_r($row);
   }
```

The error that i'm always getting with sqlsrv_connect:

```
SQLSTATE: IMSSP
code: -49
message: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL 
Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server for x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
SQLSTATE: IM002
code: 0
message: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

With PDO(ODBC):

```
SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

With PDO(mssql):  could not find driver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187321/discussion-between-quasimodos-clone-and-bruno-goncalves).

Answer (score 0):

With PDO the right syntax is :

```
$dbh = new PDO ("**sqlsrv**:Server=$hostname,$port;Database=$dbname","$username","$pw");
```